Daily partition cannot retrieve and store data based on the schedule
I have the following asset in dagster:
@asset(
    partitions_def=DailyPartitionsDefinition(start_date=DATE_INIT_DAILY_ENTSOE),
    io_manager_key="postgres_io_manager",
    group_name="entsoe_daily",
    op_tags={"dagster/concurrency_key": "entsoe", "concurrency_tag": "entsoe"},
    description="The day-ahead prices for each market time unit (60m). Day-ahead prices refer to the price per MWh as it is settled each hour in the energy market. In Greece, that is HEnEx. ENTSOE's data probably comes from there, as IPTO does not list them.",
    retry_policy=RetryPolicy(max_retries=3, delay=10)
)
def day_ahead_prices_daily(context: AssetExecutionContext):

    try:
        partition_time_window = context.partition_time_window
        if not partition_time_window:
            raise ValueError("Partition time window is not available.")
        
        start, end = timewindow_to_ts(partition_time_window)
        context.log.info(f"Handling partition from {start} to {end}")
        
        series: pd.Series = entsoe_client().query_day_ahead_prices(COUNTRY_CODE, start=start, end=end)
        dataframe = sanitize_series(series, ['price'])
        return Output(value=dataframe)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        context.log.error(f"ConnectionError: {str(e)}")
        raise
    except NoMatchingDataError:
        context.log.warning(f"No matching data for the time window: {start} to {end}")
        # Skip the partition by returning a SkipReason
        return SkipReason(f"No matching data for the time window: {start} to {end}")
    except Exception as e:
        context.log.error(f"Unexpected error: {str(e)}")
        raise

and I have defined the following job/schedule:
PG_IOMANAGER_CONFIG = {
    "username": EnvVar("DATA_PG_USERNAME"),
    "password": EnvVar("DATA_PG_PASSWORD"),
    "hostname": EnvVar("DATA_PG_HOST"),
    "port": EnvVar("DATA_PG_PORT"),
    "db_name": EnvVar("DATA_PG_DB")
}

all_assets = load_assets_from_package_module(assets)

entsoe_daily_partitions_def = DailyPartitionsDefinition(start_date=DATE_INIT_DAILY_ENTSOE)

entsoe_daily_job = define_asset_job(
    "entsoe_daily_job",
    selection=AssetSelection.groups("entsoe_daily"),
    partitions_def=entsoe_daily_partitions_def
)

entsoe_daily_schedule = ScheduleDefinition(
    job=entsoe_daily_job,
    cron_schedule="0 17 * * *",  # daily at 5 PM
)

defs = Definitions(
    assets=all_assets,
    resources={
        "postgres_io_manager": PostgresIOManager(**PG_IOMANAGER_CONFIG)
    },
    schedules=[
               entsoe_daily_schedule
               ]
)

However, when the job runs automatically I get the following error:
Exceeded max_retries of 3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/execute_plan.py", line 282, in dagster_event_sequence_for_step
    for step_event in check.generator(step_events):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/execute_step.py", line 494, in core_dagster_event_sequence_for_step
    for user_event in _step_output_error_checked_user_event_sequence(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/execute_step.py", line 183, in _step_output_error_checked_user_event_sequence
    for user_event in user_event_sequence:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/execute_step.py", line 88, in _process_asset_results_to_events
    for user_event in user_event_sequence:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/compute.py", line 198, in execute_core_compute
    for step_output in _yield_compute_results(step_context, inputs, compute_fn, compute_context):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/compute.py", line 167, in _yield_compute_results
    for event in iterate_with_context(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_utils/__init__.py", line 471, in iterate_with_context
    with context_fn():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/utils.py", line 72, in op_execution_error_boundary
    raise RetryRequestedFromPolicy(
The above exception was caused by the following exception:
dagster._check.functions.CheckError: Failure condition: Has a PartitionsDefinition, so should either have a partition key or a partition key range
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/utils.py", line 54, in op_execution_error_boundary
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_utils/__init__.py", line 473, in iterate_with_context
    next_output = next(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/compute_generator.py", line 141, in _coerce_op_compute_fn_to_iterator
    result = invoke_compute_fn(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/compute_generator.py", line 129, in invoke_compute_fn
    return fn(context, **args_to_pass) if context_arg_provided else fn(**args_to_pass)
  File "/opt/dagster/app/datasets/assets/entsoe.py", line 494, in day_ahead_prices_daily
    partition_time_window = context.partition_time_window
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/context/compute.py", line 1692, in partition_time_window
    return self.op_execution_context.partition_time_window
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/context/compute.py", line 414, in partition_time_window
    return self._step_execution_context.partition_time_window
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/context/system.py", line 478, in partition_time_window
    check.failed(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_check/functions.py", line 1642, in failed
    raise CheckError(f"Failure condition: {desc}")

In summary, I want to be able to run the asset according to the schedule of the cronjob automatically. What I have observed is that I can run it manually from the dagster UI, but when it runs automatically I get the error. Any idea of how can I solve it?
